# How to use Intent correctly

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using Intents to save data and recover them in others places of my application. I have used them in others places, but now, it's not working as I hope.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {    
    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(ConstantsGCM.GCM_SENDER_ID);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;   
        NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
        String room = intent.getExtras().getString(ConstantsGCM.GCM_ROOM);      
        Intent notIntent;       
        PendingIntent contIntent;
        Notification notif; 


        notif = new Notification(icon, textStatus, time);                       
        notIntent = new Intent(contexto,RoomsActivity2.class);

        Bundle b2 = new Bundle();                                           
        b2.putString(ConstantsRooms.ROOM, room);
        notIntent.putExtras(b2);

        contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, notIntent, 0);               
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(contexto, tittle, description, contIntent);    
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;                   
        notManager.notify((int)(Math.random()*1000), notif);
```

This code is executed when a notification is coming. When I click this notification, it's executed the Activity RoomsActivities2.class. Here, I just call this code:

```
public String getMessageString(String cod){
    String result = "";
    bundle  = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null){
        result = bundle.getString(cod);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, I didn't get the last data saved in the Intent. What's it wrong? I guess that I'm not using it correctly. Why can't I get the data from the activity?

What I think that it's happening it's:
The application gets a lot of notifications, the first one works right. But, if I keep getting more notifications, the data isn't override and I always get the first one although when I debug the code, I'm setting the another data.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I suggest that you use the Eclipse debugger or add `Log.d()` calls to your code to figure out what is going on. Learning to debug your own code is a critical skill for every programmer.

Comment: Hehe, I did,, I am setting the correct data in the Intent. But, when I  recover it, it seems like another data. I was looking for the references as well to ConstantsRooms.ROOM, for figuring out where I could change the value without knowing it, but, everything seems right. I thought it could be a problem that I didn't undersand about the life-cycle of Android. I will continue investigating.

Comment: What makes you think "it seems like another data". Please edit your question to include the specific data you saw in your debugging..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it's been a while since I've worked with pending intents, but I remember two things:

replace:

```
contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, notIntent, 0);
```

with:

```
contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

That will keep the bundle around.

BUT that flag will override any existing pending intents with the newest one, you might not want that.

If you have multiple pending intents from the same context with the same intent (but different bundles!), you can use the 2nd parameter.

```
contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, requestCode, notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

as long as every pending intent has a unique `requestCode`, and even though the google dev's docs say the parameter isn't used, it actually does serve a purpose for identifying pending intent and allows duplicates with different bundles.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works pretty good. And now, I know what it means the others two parameter. Thanks.